# Регулярное выражение для парсинга url

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть ссылка вида https://domain.com/someRoute/someRoute/../.../**filename.txt**?param1=1&param2=2&...&param333=333
Как правильно написать регулярное выражение, дабы получить filename.txt - если он всегда идёт перед началом параметров (перед ?).

Comment: Не нужно вам регулярное выражение. Возьмите класс Uri и разбирайте ссылку через него.

Comment: url.Split('?')[0].Split('/').Last();

Comment: Спасибо, сделал следующим образом  Uri uri = new Uri("someUri");
                var filename = uri.Segments.LastOrDefault();